# mvc 4 how to add htmlattribute class using model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

just i am trying to add a class name through my model class

```
public partial class tblLocation { 
/*how to add html attribute class=myclass*/
public global::System.String SitePlan { get; set; }
}
```

in my view page

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SitePlan)
```

finally i need that kind of output

```
<input class="myclass" data-val="true" data-val-required="*" id="SitePlan" name="SitePlan" type="text">
```

Comment: You can create your own `Attribute` that implements `IMetadataAware` and a custom html helper, or add a property to your model `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SitePlan, new { @class = Model.YourClassNameProperty })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign the Model property name like below

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SitePlan, new { @class = Model.myclass })
```

In other way : `class="@Model.myclass"`

**Ex:**

```
<input class="@Model.myclass" data-val="true" data-val-required="*" id="SitePlan" name="SitePlan" type="text">
```

Comment: Nice solution. but sir just i dont want to write anything in my view page. i want that new { @class = Model.myclass } arrive automatically by model class

Comment: `new { @class = Model.myclass }` - You don't want to write like this or entirely you don't want to write anything in view? Without write anything in view the Css class will not be allocated from model.